# Splitting string based in multiple delimiters

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a string

> {
>   "language": "en",
>     "value": -0.06706431209772078,
>     "sent": -1
>   }

I just want to take the value

> -0.06706431209772078

as the output : 
could anyone help?

Comment: you need to `match` it **not** `split`..you should use `split` when you want multiple value..but you only want a single value..so you need to `match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use regex

```
var result = Regex.Match(@"{ ""language"": ""en"", ""value"": -0.06706431209772078, ""sent"": -1 }", @"(?<=""value"": )(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)(?=,|$)");
```

edited:

```
var result = Regex.Match(@"{ ""language"": ""en"", ""value"": -0.06706431209772078, ""sent"": -1 }", @"(?<=""value"":\s*)(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)");
```

Comment: no need of `(?=,|$)`..`(?<=""value"": )` should be `(?<=""value"":\s*)`